# Invalid value for the 'android:targetSandboxVersion' attribute in the AndroidManifest in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-sdk

I am getting below error while pushing app for beta release in google play store.

> Invalid value for the 'android:targetSandboxVersion' attribute in the AndroidManifest.

I check in my tiapp.xml but didn't found any thing related this. Any help appreciated.

> Invalid value for the 'android:targetSandboxVersion' attribute in the AndroidManifest. If publishing an Instant App, consider using the Android App Bundle to add this attribute correctly.

```xml
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:versionCode="381">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>
      <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
      <application android:theme="@style/Theme.connectMobileTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ConnectActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="companyname"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="true"/>
      </application>
    </manifest>
  </android>
```

Modules

```xml
 <modules>
    <module platform="iphone" version="1.3.0">ti.imagefactory</module>
    <module platform="android" version="4.0.0">ti.imagefactory</module>
    <module platform="iphone" version="2.2.1">bencoding.securely</module>
    <module platform="android" version="3.1.2">bencoding.securely</module>
  </modules>
```

I tried to change manually in below file but its override when build android app

```
Project/titanium/build/android/app/build/intermediates/instant_app_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml
```

[image: Google play store upload error]

Comment: are you using any android modules? and which Ti SDK version are you using?

Comment: SDK version i tried 7.4.X and 9.0.X both are having same issue. Android modules not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "not sure"? They are listed under `<modules>` in the tiapp.xml

Comment: updated description with modules

Comment: thanks! I've checked my files and the version is `android:targetSandboxVersion="2"`. Didn't set that myself but you could set a version in your `<manifest>` to override that. Are you trying to upload an instant app? That is not supported

Comment: i tried adding in manifest  `<manifest android:versionCode="385"  android:targetSandboxVersion="1">`  but still getting override to 2  yes i am try to upload instant app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading an instant app is currently not supported: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23412

Comment: how to upload apk then if not supported ?

Comment: just use the normal "app release" beta track. Not the instant-apps menu (should be right above): https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/article_attachments/360001556553/New_App_Release.png

Comment: Thanks. I am able to upload using normal app release. @miga if you feel this question was right then don't forget to upvote on question.